# PHP dealing with long integers

Tags: php, facebook, integer

I'm trying to get data from facebook. So I try to get the `user_id` from their arrays.
Problem is some `user_id` are SO LONG that when I try to get it it returns something like

`1.00003247906E+14`

instead of

`100003247905698`

How do I fix this? I need the actual `user_id`.

I tried using:

```
$targets = (string)($status->actor_id);
```

But its still returning the same.

Comment: By default, PHP will convert all integers that is out of range to float. Use BC Math to handle big integer (but seems it is a bit overwhelming)

Comment: do you need them as integers? for most cases handling them as strings should work.

Comment: OP already tried to cast it to string

Comment: No idea about Facebook but you need to retrieve the ID as string in the first place. Once it's become a PHP floating point number, you can't assure you haven't lost precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `$targets = sprintf('%0.0f',$status->actor_id)`

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix of this :

```
printf("%14.0f", 1.00003247906E+14);
```

will print

```
100003247905698
```

Comment: And how do you know that `...06` actually represents `...05698`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario according to the OP this should be the number.

Comment: That was just an example. If the knew the ID in advance, he could just define it as string in the first place. 100003247905697, 100003247905698, 100003247905699... they all print as 1.00003247906E+14.

Comment: Is there any other way? Like getting the data as string? It still wont work. :(

Comment: instead of using `printf()` to print it out, you can use `sprintf()` to get the string back

Answer (score 0):

`$targets = (string)($status->actor_id);` must be returning and invalid value, because the invalid value must already be inside $status

Are you actually printing the retrieved user_id directly (like via `print_r($status)`)?

Comment: ah k. i guess assuming code not posted in this question is probably not a good idea